# Routing specific subnet through a local peer

Tags: networking, ubuntu, routing, ipsec, strongswan

I have two (almost identical) Ubuntu machines with the local IP of `10.0.0.10` and `10.0.0.20`, let's call them **TEN** and **TWENTY** respectively. Both have the default gateway of `10.0.0.1`.

On **TEN** I have a site-to-site VPN setup (using *StrongSwan*) with a remote site (over which I have no control), which allows me to access the remote subnet `172.16.16.16/30` .

From my local machine at home, I simply use SSH port forwarding whenever I need to reach the remote subnet. But, I am wondering if it's possible to configure both machines so that, from **TWENTY**, requests to `172.16.16.16/30` (the remote subnet) are routed through `10.0.0.10`, and the response traffic is forwarded to **TWENTY** accordingly. I want all other traffic to use the default gateway.

Thanks